# Use Angelleye Paypal Express Checkout Class for Parallel Payments

Tags: php, paypal

I am using the Angelleye Paypal class to setup express checkout.
Using the demo I can accept a payment to myself for multiple items.
I have a site that advertises on behalf of people and the shopping cart is built and breaks the values into an array per seller.

How do i use the SetExpressCheckout.php to create the array for the receivers.

This is a demo of the array i have from the cart

```
Array
(
[102340] => Array
    (
        [name] => Mandy
        [paypal] => sales@one.co.uk
        [artwork] => Array
            (
                [data_id] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1034
                        [1] => 1038
                    )

                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Pink Foxgloves
                        [1] => Big Red Poppies
                    )

                [qty] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                        [1] => 1
                    )

                [price] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 260
                        [1] => 288
                    )

            )

        [amount] => 548
    )

[102341] => Array
    (
        [name] => John C
        [paypal] => sales@two.co.uk
        [artwork] => Array
            (
                [data_id] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1052
                    )

                [name] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Success
                    )

                [qty] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1
                    )

                [price] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 46.75
                    )

            )

        [amount] => 46.75
    )

)
```

So baiscally mandy has sold 2 items:

id: 1034 name: Pink Foxgloves qty: 1 subtotal : 260.00

id: 1038 name : Big red poppies qty: 1 subtotal : 288.00

And John has sold

id: 1052 name : Success qty:1 subtotal : 46.75

I also have the total of :594.75

If i can get the receivers in the express checkout it would be good and if i can also get their items as well this would be excellent.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after research and not much help anywhere i found the answer through trial and error.

In the setexpresscheckout script i had to do a foreach loop around the payment array area.

This area will then have the recipent email/paypal id the currency the amount and a unique payment request id.

within this loop i then run another loop around the items and generate a list of items purchased from that seller.

I then set this all into an array which is sent through as normally it would be for a single seller.

Heres my code but obviously this is quite specific to my task.

```
// setup the holding array for all the details
$Payments = array();
foreach ($seller as $key => $value) {
        // reset the items array for each recipient
        $PaymentOrderItems = array();
        // setup each recipient details
        $Payment = array(
            'currencycode'          => 'GBP',
            'amt'                   => $value['amount'],
            'sellerpaypalaccountid' => $value['paypal'],    
            'paymentrequestid'      => 'Payment'.$key
        );

        // loop through the products for each seller
        foreach ($value['artwork'] as $akey) {
            $Item = array(
                'number'    => $akey['data_id'],
                'desc'      => $akey['name'],
                'qty'       => $akey['qty'],
                'amt'       => round($akey['price'],2)
            );
            // push this item into the item array for this recipient
            array_push($PaymentOrderItems, $Item);
        }

        // add the item array to the payment array
        $Payment['order_items'] = $PaymentOrderItems;

        // push the payment array to the main payments array
        array_push($Payments, $Payment);
    }
```

I hope this helps anyone else that is stuck with this class that wants to use express checkout instead of adaptive payments.